# have error 404 in redirect angular app via address bar in browser

Tags: angular, nginx

have error 404 in redirect angular app via the address bar in browser but when does this work in the browser after running angular app via ng serve command everything is ok.
my config in Nginx is:

```
 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
                root “D:\Tools\nginx-1.16.0\nginx-1.16.0\html”;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
       }
```

Note:
Currently Define base in Index html file

```
 <base href="/">
```

Comment: What is the url to access the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, you can use any that suits you well:

1. Make changes in Nginx server config rule to redirect.
2. Use HashLocationStrategy of Angular

## #1

I don't know the config setting for Nginx but for IIS. You could find some equivalent of below:

```
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="samcds/index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

## 2.

In your app module, add below providers:

```
 providers: [Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
```

for referenece https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy

Comment: ty Irshad in the second solution we need any config or doing more than add your provider

Comment: Adding a provider would change the location strategy from PathLocationStrategy to HashLocationStrategy. Your path will look a little bit different (having # in url). To answer you question exactly. You don't need anything else other than adding provider.